# Is there a way to use System.Drawing in a webservice in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, system.drawing

I have a project were i need to read some "secret values" from a database, and print those values on a card. I was trying use GDI do write the values on card image, but asp.net does't allow me to use System.Drawing. Any suggestion?

Thanks

EDIT:  In the MSDN page says:
 "Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components."

Comment: You should be able to use `System.Drawing` just fine, I use it to draw  heat maps in my app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to System.Drawing.dll

[image]

Comment: Does't work, visual studio keeps complaining "C:\....\Service2.asmx.cs(11): The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the class or namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
"

Comment: @luistm Can you provide some code? Also, can you list your using statements?

Comment: The code is working, but when i add it to the webservice file and  include "using System.Drawing;" it gives the above error.

Comment: My using statements: 
using System;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Threading;

using System.Web.Mail;

using System.Web.Services;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Data.SqlTypes;

using System.Configuration;

using System.IO;

using System.Drawing;

Comment: @luistm are you sure you are using the correct version of System.Drawing.dll? check the path of the assembly you are referencing (in the image I posted, you can scroll to the right and see the path)

Comment: Hi. I discarded this approach. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for the MDX you should probably need to install the SDK.
Alternatively browse the DLL manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Drawing, but you may encounter problems is the general message. This may offer more help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/19/gdi-gdiplus-and-asp-net.aspx

Can you post some code so we might see where the error is occurring?